# Closed form of a trigonometric integral sought

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to evaluate the definite integral $I(a,b)$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$I(a,b):=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-(a+b\cos{\theta})^2}\mathrm{d}\theta.$$

Assume $a,b$ are suitably restricted to keep the integrand real-valued.

---

My attempt.

Introduce the parameter $w$ into the integrand and differentiate with respect to it:

$$\begin{align}I(a,b,w)&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-(a+b\cos{(w\theta)})^2}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
\implies \partial_w I(a,b,w)&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{b\theta\sin{(w\theta)}(a+b\cos{(w\theta)})}{\sqrt{1-(a+b\cos{w\theta})^2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=ab\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\theta\sin{(w\theta)}}{\sqrt{1-(a+b\cos{w\theta})^2}}\mathrm{d}\theta+b^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\theta\sin{(w\theta)}\cos{(w\theta)}}{\sqrt{1-(a+b\cos{w\theta})^2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\end{align}.$$

My next step would probably be to integrate by parts, but at this point I'm wondering if there is a less messy way to go about this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A completely equivalent question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/773553/73025). The result is expressed in terms of elliptic integrals:
$$\boxed{\displaystyle I(a,b)=4\sqrt{\frac{b}{k}}\,\biggl[\mathbf{E}\left(k^2\right)-\left(1-k^2\right)\mathbf{K}\left(k^2\right)+\left(1-k^2\right)\Pi\left(c^{-2}|k^2\right)\biggr]} $$

where the Mathematica conventions for the arguments of $\mathsf{EllipticE}$, $\mathsf{EllipticK}$ and $\mathsf{EllipticPi}$ are used, and the parameters $k$ and $c$ are defined by
\begin{align}
k=\frac{1+b^2-a^2-\sqrt{(1+b^2-a^2)^2-4b^2}}{2b},\qquad c=\frac{a}{b-k}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was unaware of the similar question.

Comment: @DavidH You are very welcome. The answer is somewhat involved but I think there is no way to simplify it. Even for $a=0$ it is given by an elliptic integral.

Comment: I think I agree.

Comment: @DavidH May I ask you a favor? Could you please temporarily unaccept my answer? It was downvoted and I have a suspect. But to be sure, I need to delete my post and observe the changes in his reputation. I will then undelete the answer - the whole thing will take not more than 15 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidH Thanks, I have finished with deleting/undeleting. It was indeed the suspect - the guy randomly downvotes my answers on a regular basis.

Comment: Good detective work. Surely such behavior is a violation of the rules here and should be reported, right? Also, I'll re-accept your answer if you're ready for me to.

Comment: @DavidH I flagged the post for moderator's attention (as a number of others before), though I don't think they can do much. The same user has recently got a weekly ban simultaneously with another one that I suspected to be his sockpuppet. The day before their respective upvoting reputation changes were reversed - I let you guess what happened. But now the ban is over, so the guy keeps going. Anyhow my investigation is finished :)